# How to run a simple java class on the command prompt in windows 8

Tags: java, command, prompt

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to run a java class on the command prompt. Its a very simple class and a friend of mine says it could be a problem with windows 8. Are there any suggestions. Here i'll show you the class and how I tried to compile it. I works fine in eclipse.

```
           package gmit;

           public class A {
             public static void main(String[] args) {
               System.out.println("hello");
             }
           }
```

In the command prompt I wrote
C:\Users\eclipse\workspace\Oct1stcasting\src\gmit>

followed by -       javac A.java

java A.class

I tested the class using               type A.java
and the text from the class does come up. 
What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great.

Comment: to run class with `java` you should specify only class name, without `.class`

Answer (score 1):

If it runs in an Eclipse project, but not from command line, you could try this:

```
C:\Users\eclipse\workspace\Oct1stcasting\bin\gmit>java A
```

Inside a project directory, Eclipse saves source codes in /src and bytecodes in /bin. Thus, if you simply want to run your bytecode from command line, changing directory to /bin might suffice.

Answer (score 0):

To compile

```
C:\Users\eclipse\workspace\Oct1stcasting\src\gmit>javac A.java
```

To run

```
C:\Users\eclipse\workspace\Oct1stcasting\src\gmit>java A
```

Don't append the .class extension while running the java program

Answer (score 0):

Don’t add a `.class` suffix when using the `java` command.

Use `java A` or `java -cp . A`. The latter is required if the current directory is not implicitly used as class path.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation:

```
C:\Users\eclipse\workspace\Oct1stcasting\src>javac gmit/A.java
```

Executing:

```
C:\Users\eclipse\workspace\Oct1stcasting\src>java gmit/A
```